# What is the name for the integer part of a enum?

Tags: c#, programming-practices, enum, languages

I've been writing some code comments, and I've been trying to refer to the index integer of a enum type, but I'm not sure what it's called. I'm tempted to call it the identifier, however there is likely a word that already exists.

It's hopefully easier to see what I mean with a example.

```
    enum Weekday
    {
        Monday,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A test method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="weekdayId">The ... for the enum weekday</param>
    void test(int weekdayId)
    {

    }
```

I'm leaning towards identifier, as that seems to fit with my comment, but I just wanted to check first that there wasn't a word already. If not I think it should be called the gloopdedoop.

Comment: In other languages, it may be called the _ordinal_.

Comment: In even other languages, it may be called the *discriminant*.

Comment: Just "value" works and even already has precedent: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C# enums are [a set of named [integral numeric] constants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum).

Each constant in the enum has a numeric value. So the word you are looking for, for the "*the index integer of a enum*", is just "value".

Comment: So something like "The value of the desired constant inside the enum 'Weekday' ". I'm dubious as to whether that is clear, but it doesn't seem to be easily misconstrued so I guess that's what I'll use, thanks.

Comment: Something like "The value of the enum". That's it. The name of the enum is the "named constant" (Friday) the value of the enum Fridays is 5 (or whatever).

Comment: @robbie-dee, please don't change "numeric" to "integer". C# enum values can be any of the [integral numeric types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types), not just `integer`.

Comment: @DavidArno Numeric could be taken to mean floating point types - hence my change, but feel free to be wrong (again) :)

Comment: @DubDub: Arguably, you can call `Weekday.Friday` a value just as much as `5` (its integer counterpart) is a value. But since these are completely interchangeable from a C# perspective, it often doesn't particularly matter to distinguish between them. When it does, using "integer value" to distinguish seems more than adequate.

Comment: This is incorrect for the reason I've described. It *must* be an integral type. Simply calling it numeric is wrong.

Comment: @RobbieDee fine, I’ll give in to yours and Belgian Dog’s  pedanticism. Changed it to “integral numeric” <shrug/>

Answer (score 4):

You're just talking about the *integral value* here. I'd avoid using the word "index" as it doesn't necessarily follow that it will be an index in the way you describe. You can set any values for enumerations - they don't have to start at zero or one or even be consecutive.

I'd also strongly avoid referring them as numerics as that has a very specific meaning in programming - those being the super set of all integer *AND* floating point types. Best to avoid the confusion.

But generally speaking, I've heard programmers refer to the enum value as simply "the value" or "underlying value". It is taken as understood (by seasoned programmers) that it is an integer.

Comment: FWIW, in *Java* it is officially called the ordinal. (But Java enums are entirely different from C# enums!)

Comment: "*It is taken as understood (by seasoned programmers) that it is an integer.*" And `integer` has a specific meaning too. But really experienced programmers understand that by "integer" you mean "any value within the numeric range supported by the chosen underlining type of the enum". Of course inexperienced programmers might assume only integers are allowed. So by being incorrectly pedantic, you've sown more confusion. Which is why it's better to just use the general term "numeric" and guide the user to a precise description of supported numeric types and values. Just as I did.